# Trying to understand a detour (hooking) function

Tags: c++, winapi

Hi I'm trying to understand a function, it's about Windows API hooking. I'm trying to hook LoadLibraryA to see if any cheats are trying to inject into my game. For that I'm trying to intercept any calls to LoadLibraryA.

I tried to write comments to explain what I think is going on, but I'm unsure about the latter parts

```
// src = address of LoadLibraryA in kernel32.dll,
// dst = my function prototype of LoadLibraryA
// len = 5, as we allocate a JMP instruction (0xE9)
PVOID Detour(BYTE* src, const BYTE* dst, const int len)
{
    BYTE* jmp = (BYTE*)malloc(len + 5); // allocate 10 bytes

    DWORD oldProtection; // change protection of 5 bytes starting from LoadLibraryA in kernel32.dll
    VirtualProtect(src, len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection); // Changes the protection on a region of committed pages in the virtual address space of the calling process.

    memcpy(jmp, src, len); // save 5 first bytes of the start of LoadLibraryA in kernel32.dll from src to jmp
    jmp += len; // start from byte 6

    jmp[0] = 0xE9; // insert jump from byte 6 - 10: 
    // jmp looks like this currently: [8BFF] = 2 bytes [55] = 1 byte [8BEC] = 2 bytes [0xE9] = 5 bytes

    // ??
    *(DWORD*)(jmp + 1) = (DWORD)(src + len - jmp) - 5; // ?

    // ??
    src[0] = 0xE9;
    *(DWORD*)(src + 1) = (DWORD)(dst - src) - 5; // ?

    // Set the same memory protection as before.
    VirtualProtect(src, len, oldProtection, &oldProtection); 

    // ??
    return (jmp - len);
}
```

Below is the representation before the hook and after.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Why do you hook an API that no sane (read: Unicode-aware) application is going to call?

Comment: It's for the proof of concept, could be any api function, but some remote dll injectors do use  loadlibraryA and W

Comment: So, what's your question? Why your code occasionally faults due to an invalid opcode? Or whether there's a more [supported way to hook API calls](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110921-00/?p=9583)?

Comment: The function works fine, just need help in understanding whats going on in the later part of the function. I'm unsure what happens from here `jmp += len;` Thanks for the link though :-)

Comment: @IInspectable `LoadLibraryA()` is commonly used in remote DLL injection, in part because it requires an injector to allocate less memory in the target process than uing `LoadLibraryW()`. And maybe the injecting app is compiled for ANSI rather than Unicode to begin with. But whatever the case, it would make sense to hook both `LoadLibraryA()` and `LoadLibraryW()`, just in case

Comment: @Hummas you should read up on what a Detour actually is and how it works: [Detours: Binary Interception of Win32 Functions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/detours-binary-interception-of-win32-functions/). That will explain to you exactly what this code is doing.

Comment: You are linking to the MS Detour library, I'm looking into how it's done without MS Detour lib. Should have stated that. Thank you for the link, however :-)

Comment: @rem No matter what character encoding any given binary is compiled for, every API call will eventually call into the Unicode implementation. Hooking the Unicode implementation will thus intercept *any* API call, whereas hooking the ANSI version will catch only some. If there were any memory allocation required, it would be identical amounts for the ANSI and Unicode versions. As it stands, there isn't any allocation required at all, when detouring through the hot-patch point.

Comment: @Hummas if you actually read the page I linked to, there is a published document that explains the technical details of what a detour is and how it works at the instruction level, regardless of the detouring library used.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, I know what a detour is, I had a problem understanding what practically happen in that code, as stated in my post. But thanks for the link - as stated earlier as well. I can also refer this site here: http://jbremer.org/x86-api-hooking-demystified/. It's a good resource as well. Now leave it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function works fine, just need help in understanding whats going on in the later part > of the function. I'm unsure what happens from here jmp += len;

First thing I notice is your code is doing the detour and the jmp back all in one go, which is different than I usually see people do it.

> memcpy(jmp, src, len);

You're copying the stolen bytes to the location of your shellcode

jmp is the address you're jumping to

> jmp += len;

length is the number of stolen bytes, or bytes you overwrite which are copied to the area you jmp too, because you must still execute them.  So your advancing to the byte directly following your relative jmp in your shellcode

> jmp[0] = 0xE9;

You're writing the relative jump instruction

> *(DWORD*)(jmp + 1) = (DWORD)(src + len - jmp) - 5;

jmp + 1 = the address after the jmp instruction where you need to place the relative address

`(src + len - jmp) - 5` is the equation required to get the relative address

> src[0] = 0xE9;
>   *(DWORD*)(src + 1) = (DWORD)(dst - src) - 5;

You're doing the same thing you did inside your shellcode except you're just creating the detour to it in this case.

> return (jmp - len);

You're returning the address of the shellcode (this is kinda weird but you have to do this because your code did `jmp +=len`)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, it makes sense now! Thank you!